# Using _ignored field in kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have the `_ignored` field created when [ignored_malformed](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ignore-malformed.html) is enabled.
I want to create a dashboard to show those fields in a piechart or something similar
But I can't find this field in Kibana, nor does it appear in the mapping.

[image: _ignored field in buckets]

Comment: Can you ensure that you have "refreshed" your index mapping in the Kibana management interface for your index pattern? Should be like Management->Kibana->Index Patterns -> {Your Pattern} -> Refresh

Comment: @IanGabes It's not in the mapping at all. It's a special field.
I guess it doesn't have keyword type, so I'm not sure if it's possible at all..

Comment: Looks like you are right! I tested locally, and the _ignored field doesn't get added to the mapping. It might not be possible?

Comment: Yeah looks like it's not possible yet. But I created an issue on github. Upvote if you think it's useful
https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/59946